# How to show the personalized messages issued by ajax in each corresponding input?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

**This is how my code works:**

My Ajax code works perfectly, I receive the error responses, and upon receiving a correct answer the form shows me the message, hides the form, and redirects to another page of the same site.

***What I want to achieve in the code Ajax***

What I want is to be able to show the personalized messages in each input field that corresponds to your error message and not show it globally in a certain part, my idea is to show the messages in each field, if only PHP code would be simple but I am using Ajax .

*How can I show the messages in each input?*

**My code Ajax is:**

```
$(function() {
    var frm = $('#resetform');
    frm.submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var formData = frm.serialize();
        formData += '&' + $('#submit_btn').attr('name') + '=' + $('#submit_btn').attr('value');
        $.ajax({
            type: frm.attr('method'),
            url: frm.attr('action'),
            data: formData,
        })
        .done(function(data) {
            let res = JSON.parse(data);
            if(res.status){
                $('#message').fadeIn();
                $('#message').html(res.message).delay(3000).fadeOut(3000);
                $(frm).hide();
        setTimeout(function(){
            location.href = 'index.php';
        },2000);
      } else {
        $('#message').fadeIn();
        $('#message').html(res.message).delay(3000).fadeOut(3000);
      }
        })
        .fail(function() {
            $('#message').fadeIn();
            $('#message').html(textStatus).delay(2000).fadeOut(2000);
        })
    });
});
```

**My code PHP** `changepass.php`

```
if (isset($_POST['password_change'])) {
    $user = $_POST['username'];
    $old_password = $_POST['old_password'];
    $new_password = $_POST['new_password'];
    $con_password = $_POST['con_newpassword'];

    if($con_password !== $new_password){
        echo json_encode(['status'=> false, 'message'=>"Passwords do not match!"]);
        exit;
    }

    $stmtUsers = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM users where username=? limit 1");
    $stmtUsers->bind_param("s", $username);
    $stmtUsers->fetch();
    $stmtUsers->close();

    if (!password_verify($old_password, $result['password'])) {
        echo json_encode(['status'=> false, 'message'=>"The password is not valid!"]);
        exit;
    }

    $hash = password_hash($new_password, CRYPT_BLOWFISH);

    $stmtUpdate = $con->prepare("UPDATE `users` SET `password` = ? WHERE `username` = ?");
    $stmtUpdate->bind_param("ss", $hash, $username);
    if($stmtUpdate->execute()){
        echo json_encode(['status'=> true, 'message'=>"Password changed successfully!"]);
    } else{
         echo json_encode(['status'=> false, 'message'=>"The password could not be updated!"]);
    }
```

**My form:**

```
<form name="resetform" action="changepass.php" id="resetform" class="passform" method="post" role="form">
    <h3>Change Your Password</h3>
    <br />
    <label>Enter Old Password</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="old_password" id="old_password">
    <label>Enter New Password</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="new_password" id="new_password">
    <label>Confirm New Password</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control"  name="con_newpassword"  id="con_newpassword" />
    <br>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-warning" name="password_change" id="submit_btn" value="Change Password" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the simplest way to achieve this (based on your current code) is to return input element identifiers (eg. `name`) along with the error message. For example, in server side (php):

```
echo json_encode([
    'status'=> false,
    'message'=> [
        "con_newpassword" => "Passwords do not match!"
    ]
]);
```

Then in the client side (js):

```
let res = JSON.parse(data);
if(res.status){
    // do something
} else {
    for (let name in res.message) {
        // adjust this element according to your styling need
        let msg = '<span class="error">' + res.message[name] + '</span>';
        $(msg).insertAfter($('[name=' + name + ']', '#resetform'));
    }
}
```

Finally, you may want to delete all error messages at some points (eg. on re-submission) with something like this:

```
frm.submit(function(e){
    $('.error', '#resetform').remove();
    // some other code
}
```

Comment: If, friend, it works wonderfully, but I can not hide the error message for certain seconds :( `for (let name in res.message) {
           $('.error').fadeIn();
           $('.error').html(res.message).delay(3000).fadeOut(3000);
           let msg = '<span class="error">' + res.message[name] + '</span>';
           $(msg).insertAfter($('[name=' + name + ']', '#resetform'));
       }`

Comment: It should work, my friend. You just need to call the `fadeIn`, `delay` and `fadeOut` after `inserAfter`, not before. This is a simplified example http://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/625906/